# Unable to copy-paste Winforms controls from a form in a vb.net project to a form in a c# project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, copy, controls

for a big refactoring project of about 140 forms I've been trying to copy and paste these controls through the designer. I'm using VS 2022 but I've also tried with 2019. The origin project is in .NET4.5 and the new project is in dotnet6. My machine is running on win10.

These are the things I've tried so far:

- keyboard shortcuts ( ctrl-a + ctrl-c / ctrl-x + ctrl-v )
- Drag 'n drop ( ctrl-a + drag + drop )
- Same methods as above but one control at a time ( total size of clip is 164k bytes )

[image]

The paste option in the context menu of the c# form is grayed out and when I drag 'n drop I'm shown a "blocking" icon.

I'm at a loss and not about to redesign all these forms.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Try reading [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/78236c26-2497-4882-b59b-0b3326905936/new-to-c-copy-vb-form-controls-to-c-form?forum=csharpgeneral#:~:text=Open%20a%20VB%20project%2C%20select,after%20pasting%20them%20in%20C%23.). In some cases in can be, in some cases it can't be, depending on the controls or other variables.

Comment: You can import an existing Form built with .Net Framework in a .Net 5 / 6 Project. Right click `Project-> Add -> Existing item`, select the Form (only the main `.vb` file, not the designer or the .resx files), wait a couple of seconds for the Form to be *converted* (not really a conversion), until the usual Icon appears, then open it, select its controls and copy/paste them somewhere else. Dismiss the Form after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/winform-controls-fw4x-cannot-by-copied-to-net-5-wi/1257006) post, .NET framework 4.x is incompatible at the binary level with .NET core which prevents you from copying over controls. Logical really when I come to think about it.

I've tested with dotnet5.0 and dotnet6.0 both giving issues but dotnet4.8 works just fine.

As a solution to my problem I will try using an intermediate project in .NET framework 4.8 using c# and afterwards porting to dotnet6.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It seems that you have found a solution to the question, then please consider [accepting your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: I will, can only do so after 2 days ( now 21 hours )

Answer (score 1):

I just did some testing and it appears that you cannot drag and drop - or copy and paste, presumably - between different instances of VS, which you appear to be trying to do. I opened the same solution twice and I was able to drag and drop between C# and VB projects in the same instance but I wasn't able to do so between two forms in the same VB project between instances.

This means that you will have to add one of the projects to the solution containing the other. That's not a big deal because adding an existing project to a solution doesn't move or copy that project. The solution simply refers to it in its existing location. Once you've done all the drag and drop, you can simply remove the project from the solution again and you're done.

Comment: Yes, this will work.

Comment: @user17922293, Thank you for your comment. I should point out that I was also using one instance of vs. The "other" instance you see in my image is just a detached tab. 

Also all the projects are in the same solution.

Comment: @Wauter, it worked for me with just a `Button` and a `TextBox`. I suggest that you test a simple scenario like that and see whether it works for you. If it does then there's obviously something specific about your current scenario that is creating the issue, so you'd need to do more testing to work out what that is. Once you know what the issue is, you may be able to work out how to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly copy control from .NET Framework 4.x to .NET6 in winform application, because .NET Framework and .NET6 are different frameworks, so if your project only targets windows, you can consider updating the project to .NET Framework 4.8 which allows you to copy-paste Winforms controls.

In order to convert VB project(.NET Framework) to C# project(.NET6), one of the option is to convert VB code in the InitializeComponent method to C#, and paste it into the same location in .NET 6.

Also check : [Upgrade a Windows Forms App to .NET 6 with the .NET Upgrade Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-winforms-framework)

Note: some libraries in .NET Framework are not supported on .NET6, you may need to find their alternatives.